# Quaternion.Lerp not working properly in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm using `Quaternion.Lerp` to rotate a joint with a certain angle, but when I use the below code I find the joint rotating very far although I specified it to rotate with only 5. Any thoughts please?

```
newRot.y += currentTransform.localRotation.y + 5f;
blendWeight = 0;
if ( blendWeight < 1)
{
    animationRotation = currentTransform.transform.localRotation;
    newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(newRot.x, newRot.y, newRot.z);
    blendWeight += Time.deltaTime/0.9f;
    currentTransform.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp (animationRotation,newRotation, blendWeight);
}
```

where newRot is a `Vector3`

Comment: Is that code correct? The first line doesn't seem like it should compile, and the lerp won't even be called. Can you modify your example into something that works and exhibits the problem that you're having?

Comment: @Sam the code is correct, it's just a snapshot of only this part, for sure the code is much bigger. But yeah, it works like that without any compilation errors.

Comment: Oops I misread the 'if' test so the lerp will run. But the first line seems weird: `Transform newRot.y += currentTransform.localRotation.y + 5f;` are you sure this compiles without error? This should be a syntax error. Are you using C# or JavaScript (UnityScript)?

Comment: Ok. That definitely isn't valid C# so you should be getting an error message.

Comment: sorry, it is a Vector3 not Transform. My mistake, I apologise for this. It's just because it was defined in another place of the code. I updated it in the question, so if you could please advise.

Comment: You're code does not compile

Comment: Check out @artemisart's answer. Changing the `y` value of a quaternion is not the same as rotating around the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add 5 degrees to y, you must use eulerAngles and not directly rotation (which il a quaternion). Generaly speaking you should never set the xyzw components of a quaternion.

If you want y slowly rotates an object, consider using RotateTowards (for a given target orientation) or transform.Rotate (for a given speed).

Comment: In addition to what artemisart said, if you are adding five every update, be aware that Update will be called at whatever your framerate is. So if your framerate is 60 fps, in one second you will have added five 60 times. If your framerate varies, then in one second you will have added a different amount. You should really add 5 * Time.deltaTime.

Comment: if I didn't use the lerp and only used this `currentTransform.Rotate(newRot);` it works as anticipated and the limb's joint only rotates a little bit, but it kinds of jump directly to the new rotation without smooth transition. So not sure how can I apply this rotation with smooth rotations.

Comment: Multiply with Time.deltaTime for smooth transitions, as Sam said.